# How to use axes programmatically in Gnuplot?

Tags: bash, plot, gnuplot, axis

If you need to draw some graphs against `x1y1` or `x1y2` axes, depending on the maximum y value of each graph, what would be the proper syntax for that?

My data file has several columns. The first one contains x values, the others y1, y2 and so on.
After using the stats command, I could easily define each axis value for each graph:

```
stats '$data_file' u 1:2 nooutput;
y1max = STATS_max_y;
if (y1max > ymax) { y1axis = 'x1y2' } else { y1axis = 'x1y1' };
stats '$data_file' u 1:3 nooutput;
y2max = STATS_max_y;
if (y2max > ymax) { y2axis = 'x1y2' } else { y2axis = 'x1y1' };
...
```

After that, I can draw the graphs with this `plot` cmd

```
plot '$data_file' using 1:2 axes x1y1 notitle with lines lc rgb 'black' lw 1,\
               '' using 1:3 axes x1y2 notitle with lines lc rgb 'green' lw 1;
```

which works, but it is not programmatically at all.

But this one <s>doesn't</s> works

```
plot '$data_file' using 1:2 axes @y1axis notitle with lines lc rgb 'black' lw 1,\
               '' using 1:3 axes @y2axis notitle with lines lc rgb 'green' lw 1;
```

where I used the `Substitution of string variables as macros` (The character @ is used to trigger substitution of the current value of a string variable into
the command line...) which is written in the [docs](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html).

Nor the `eval` command likes to work for me.

Could you please provide an example for that purpose, which is working or any a good advise. THX!

Comment: Your plot command with macros looks good. Do you have macros enabled? This should be the case by default for versions >= 5.0. Check `show macros` and enable it with `set macros`, if it is not already done. Otherwise: do you get an error, or are the selected axes wrong?

Comment: The commands you show with macro substitution work here, tested in both 5.2.8 and 5.4.0.   Is there more to it that you are not showing?  For example, it would *not* work if the macro and plot commands are inside an iteration clause in curly brackets `do for [i=1:10] {  macro=foo; plot baz axes @macro ... }`.  This is because the macro substitution is done before loop execution, so the assignment to redefine the macro inside the loop has no effect.

Comment: @Christoph: If I use `show macros` the return value is just an empty line. What should be the expected value?

Comment: @Ethan: Thx for the explanation. I don't use a loop.

Comment: I used the above syntax in a bash script. CopyPaste to the gnuplot cmd line rises the same error or warning: `warning: y3axis is not a string variable` and therefore `axes must be x1y1, x1y2, x2y1 or x2y2`. But after you both said the cmd is working, THX a lot, I found the mistake, while reading the thread ( https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/gnuplot-beta/thread/4D95784C.30204@lbl.gov/ ). I used the code as an oneliner but this could not work as written in the docs ( ...since the macro is defined on the same line and will not be expanded in time...), but I missed it. All works now!THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got two errors/warnings when using the above code in a bash script as an oneliner the following way

```
echo "gnuplot cmds;plot ..." | gnuplot
```

- warning: y3axis is not a string variable
- axes must be x1y1, x1y2, x2y1 or x2y2

As written in the docs, **the macro could not be expanded the same time as it is defined**, what is the case if written on the same line.

To avoid the above mistake we have to use only

`echo` **`-e`** `"gnuplot cmds;`**`\n`**`plot ..." | gnuplot`

and it works like it should.

Credits to @Christoph and @Ethan who put me on the right track.